# How to replace zeros in the array, with elements of another array in java

Tags: java, arrays

import java.util.Arrays;
public class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    int[] a = {1,2,3,0,0,0};
    int[] b = {7,9,13};
    
    //resultant array: a={1,2,3,7,9,13}
```

}

Comment: Could you share code for what you have tried?

Comment: Did you tried anything ?Do the number of 0's in the array `a` equals the size of the array `b`?

Comment: @SayanBhattacharya yes, equal.

Comment: @Kaan a=Arrays.copyOf(b,b.length);
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
I've tried this. it's just replacing the non-zero elements with b elements.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Iterate through array A and replace elements with value zero with elements from B.

```
int n = a.length();
int m = b.length();
int j = 0;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
  if(a[i] == 0 && j<m){a[i]=b[j];j++;}
}
```

Comment: Providing code is not going to help the OP learn anything.